# " Couldn't get connection factory client" Android Problem

Tags: android

Is there anybody solved this problem or stil is a bug? I checked  [google site](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/94e3d0454612d143) but no good news..

Answer (score 2):

I had reinstalled Android dev kit on my new system and the debug.keystore had changed.
Once I used the keytool to make a new MD5 and registered that with Google I was back in action with a fresh apiKey.

"Couldn't get connection factory client" is a weird message for an invalid apiKey !

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps (Eclipse IDE):

1) Delete debug.keystore (if you are using this default keystore, if not you'll surely know the one that you are using)

2) Clean project: Project --> Clean --> Selected projects, and you should select your MapActivity project and accept.

3) Try to run the project, It should give you error, but this action will regenerate your debug.keystore. Right click on project --> Run As --> Android project

4) Sign in for fresh new ApiKey as usual and change the old ApiKey that you put before in your MapView control. If you have JDK 1.7 be careful that it is a bit diferent command to obtain MD5 key.

Also you should have:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

permission set in Manifiest.xml

I agree with you Someone Somewhere. ¿Why they don't say clearly: ApiKey error?